# using Zend_Service_Twitter_Search with authenticated requests

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter, oauth

I need to know how to integrate Zend_Service_Twitter_Search with zend_oauth, I was using it without OAuth, but later twitter announced that they will request authentication on every endpoint, even the public ones, so now I need to authenticate Zend_Service_Twitter_Search request.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with "sending Tweets" this way (you can get the oAuth Tokens generated for your own account on [Dev Site](https://dev.twitter.com/) of Twitter):

```
 /**
 * Create new Twitter client
 * 
 * @return Zend_Service_Twitter 
 */
protected function getTwitterClient()
{
    $token = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();

    $token->setParams(array(
        'oauth_token'        => 'o auth token',
        'oauth_token_secret' => 'o auth secret',
    ));

    $twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
        'consumerKey'    => 'consumer key',
        'consumerSecret' => 'consumer secret',
        'accessToken'    => $token
    ));

    return $twitter;
}
```

Comment: But I'm using zend_service_twitter_search, not zend_service_twitter, which doesn't take accessToken param.